# I need get output using excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get output on below table using Excel function.

I have tried Index match but it only helps to get output for first value, while I have duplicate values.

Database

```
  Date      Product Name
01-01-2016  60      A
01-01-2016  54      B
01-01-2016  40      C
01-01-2016  60      D
01-03-2016  47      A
01-03-2016  39      B
01-03-2016  46      C
01-03-2016  42      D
01-02-2016  37      A
01-02-2016  53      B
01-02-2016  25      C
01-02-2016  46      D
01-04-2016  49      A
01-04-2016  47      B
01-04-2016  46      C
01-04-2016  27      D
```

Need a help to fill the below table using Excel formula

Kindly find the below sample output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqnRo.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What should be in the table below? Can you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: Agreed, without more information it seems to me you would need to look into Index combined with Match function.

Comment: Hi I have added the required output image

Comment: Have a search on here - there are q&a which do roughly what you want but you will need to edit to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using your posted "database" graph (the first one) as a reference and assuming that it starts in cell A1, I put your "required output" data in F1:J5. "A" starts in F2, F1 is blank and the dates are in cells G1:J1.

In G2 put this Array formula and then fill down to the last letter "D": = INDEX($B$1:$B$17,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$17=$F2,ROW($C$2:$C$17),""),COLUMN()-6)). Then fill across. The "COLUMN()-6" in the Small function assumes that you put your "required out" data in the range F1:J5; otherwise, you will need to change it manually.